# C++ multi threaded server

Tags: c++, multithreading, winsock2

I'm working on a server that just connects a client and sends back what they type. So far it works well, but I want to make it multi-threaded so I can connect more clients, so they can "Talk." Can you guys refer me to any source code that I can look over to make some adjustments to my own code? Thanks. I would also like this to work on different networks, and I am not sure how to do this so some source code to that as well would work. Also I'm in eighth grade and haven't had a lot of experience so a well-explained answer would be appreciated.

```
int main() {

    WSADATA wsaData;

    // Initialize Winsock
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if(iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;      // Internet address family is unspecified so that either an IPv6 or IPv4 address can be returned
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;    // Requests the socket type to be a stream socket for the TCP protocol
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    // Create a SOCKET for the server to listen for client connections
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Error at socket(): %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("bind failed: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    // To listen on a socket
    if ( listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("listen failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET ClientSocket;

    ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);

    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
    int iSendResult;

    // reveice until the client shutdown the connection
    do {
        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            char msg[DEFAULT_BUFFER_LENGTH];
            memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
            strncpy(msg, recvbuf, iResult);

            printf("Received: %s\n", msg);

            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);

            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }

            printf("Bytes sent: %ld\n", iSendResult);
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
        {
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            //return 1;
        }
    } while (iResult > 0);

    // Free the resouces
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) you don't *need* multiple threads to serve multiple clients. 2) threads *will* complicate your code and make it *hard* to get correct. 3) even with threads you probably want to use a thread pool, not simply one thread per connection.

Comment: It is not a real question. 1) It is too broad 2) opinion based 3) so on...

Comment: It's good to see somebody learning C++ in 8th grade, and I wish you the best.  That said, you might want to do some quick googling before you ask next time to prevent downvotes.  Googling "Simple C++ Chat Server" gives [this](https://github.com/hassanyf/Simple-Server-and-Chat-Program) as a first result, and there's plenty more great examples for you to look at.  If you want to see something meatier, try looking into IRC source code, IRC is a classic chat program that's a bit more complex, but still lean enough to study in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: It's bad to see somebody can't googling in 8th grade=) No offence, just a joke. I would be really honoured if some seniors taught me to google =)

Comment: "I want to make it multi-threaded so I can connect more than clients, ..." typo?  ... sentence incomplete? what (other than clients) might you want to connect?

Comment: I recommend you research the 'select' concept of handling multiple i/o channels with a single task.  Multiple threads imply context-switching, which is comparatively expensive, and thus probably something to avoid.  There is a use for threads, so this might be an opportunity for you to learn if this is a reasonable approach for your effort.   Good luck.

Comment: Is this C++ code when you have `printf`?

Comment: I  recommend you avoid the 'select' concept of handling multiple i/o channels with a single task.  Multiple threads allow context-switching, which avoids app-wide delays from blocking calls, allows effective use of multiple cores and does not involve you in writing explicit state-machines to handle any protocol more complex than 'echo'.  [AKA - Q. is too broad or opinion-based] :)

Comment: I cant use github at school and all the source code is for linux pthreads when Im using windows also I cant use very many forums for examples because they are all blocked. I should have mentioned this thanks

Answer (score 4):

There are dozens of ways how to implement this solution.

First of all, it is better to design what approach is preferable for your educational purposes.

#### Considering network programming:

One of the best guides for network programming I can recommend is [Beej's Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/).

#### Considering server-side architecture:

I would like to recommend C++ Concurrency in Action: Practical Multithreading by  Anthony Williams for further reading.

Before you, a whole sea of possibilities - go for it!

#### Ps: considering general questions like this

It is better to look for an answer to such questions in [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110202/state-machines-vs-threads) forum.